# VBA Nested Do While Loop vs. Nested Do While If Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to compare values within a column ("B") to a cell referenced to ("A1"). If the values in Column "B" equal "A1" I want it to count up. When it gets to the end of Column "B" I'm trying to get it to loop back and compare values in column "B" with "A2", etc. For example:

[image]

So Far I've written two different codes one with a nested do while loop and a nested do while if loop but i cant get them to loop through the whole column

```
Sub CountDb()
Dim i As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim initial As Long

i = 1
iRow = 1
initial = 1

Do While Cells(iRow, "A").Value <> "" 'initial loop, whilst there are values in cell "A" continue the loop 
    Do While Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(iRow, "A").Value 'nested while loop, comparing the first B1 and cell A1.
        If True Then Cells(i, "C") = initial 'if they A1 and B1 are equal, print 1 in column C
        initial = initial + 1 'and move on comparing A1 with B2
        If False Then
            i = i + 1 'if not satisfied, move on to cell B2 etc. 
    Loop
iRow = iRow + 1 'when you get to the end of column B, start again and compare values with A2 and B
Loop
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CountDb()
Dim i As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim initial As Long
'same comments as above, just different methodology
i = 1
iRow = 1
initial = 1

Do While Cells(iRow, "A").Value <> ""
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(iRow, "A").Value Then
        Cells(i, "C") = initial
    Else

    initial = initial + 1
    i = i + 1

    End If

    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT - fixed up column references 
**EDIT - applied comments to code

Comment: You're looping through columns `"MX", `"MS"` and `"MW"`... if your data it truly in columns `A`,`B` and `C` then you need to change those for starters...

Comment: I don't believe `If True Then` and `If False Then` in your first loop is the proper syntax, but you're close!

Comment: What are you expecting `If True Then` and `If False Then` to do? Try putting a breakpoint (F9) before the first loop, and stepping through your code (F8).

Comment: My bad, this is for a big project so forgot to change the referenced columns, just changed it to make it easier to understand

Comment: To clarify a couple of comments, `If True Then` will *always* be triggered, as the condition `If __CONDITION__ Then` is always satisfied. Similarly, `If False Then` will *never* be triggered. If you add comments to your code (lines starting with an apostrophe) it would be clearer what you expect each bit to do.

Comment: If the Boolean function returns true comparing the two cells, i want the code to print set value in column "C" , and continue through - i think this might be where im going wrong...

Comment: Hint: `If True Then` is a constant expression; anything after `Then` will unconditionally execute. `If False Then` is also a constant expression; anything after `Then` is semantically unreachable code. Multi-line `If...Then` syntax commands an `End If` token somewhere - that first block can't compile.

Comment: `Do While <Condition> Loop` will do at least 1 run, check the condition and if it's false it will exit. The test you have in your nested loop (`If True`, which doesn't do anything) is already executed before you do your if statement.
N.b. is there any reason you don't just use `=COUNTIF()` but VBA instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, i as integer, j as integer, initial as integer
Set sht = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Don't forget to change this
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    initial = 1
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To lastrow
        If Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value Then
            Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value = initial
            initial = initial + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I prefer using `For` loops as opposed to `While`s, just because I can see the ranges being looped through more easily. Here we use nested `For` loops, the first to loop through column A, the second to loop through column B. `If` our value in column A equals our value in column B, we place the initial number in column C using our variable from the nested loop.

Notice how to make this work, we re-initialize our `lastrow` variable to make the ranges for our loops.

[image: BeforeAfter]

Comment: "Try this {code dump}" answers don't teach anything. Also unqualified `Range` calls are implicitly referring to `ActiveSheet` (or implicitly, `Me.Range` if the code is in a worksheet's code-behind module), which may or may not be in `ThisWorkbook`, and may or may not be `sht`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I edited and added more explicit references. I felt that OP had a good enough grasp on the concept to understand what I was writing, as he had 2 attempts that were "close" but flawed.

Comment: When I see `If True Then ...` and then `If False Then...`, I assume OP doesn't have a grasp on the basic-basics ;-) thanks for editing, upvoted.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That's true :S (no pun intended).

Comment: Thanks fellas, yeah im defs still a rook trying things out of his league ahah

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to use countif.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngOrg As Range, rngDB As Range
    Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Set Wf = WorksheetFunction

    Set rngOrg = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rngDB = Range("b1", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = rngDB.Rows.Count
    ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 1)
    For Each Rng In rngDB
        i = i + 1
        If Wf.CountIf(rngOrg, Rng) Then
            vR(i, 1) = Wf.CountIf(Range("b1", Rng), Rng)
        End If
    Next Rng
    Range("c1").Resize(n) = vR

End Sub
```

Comment: Equally you could add this method directly as worksheet functions, removing the need for VBA

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method, this time using `Find`. This is *probably* quicker than the looping method since it leverages the in-built find function to skip to the next match.

I've commented the code below for clarity, but basically we loop through values in column `A` (using a `For` loop because they're less prone to disguised infinite looping than `While`) and look for them in column `B`.

**Note**: This looks a bit longer, but that's mainly because (a) I've added lots of comments and (b) I've used a `With` statement to ensure the ranges are *fully qualified*.

```
Sub countdb()
    Dim c As Range, fnd As Range, listrng As Range, cnt As Long, addr As String
    ' Use with so that our ranges are fully qualified
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ' Define the range to look up in (column B in this case)
        Set listrng = .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        ' Loop over values in the index range (column
        For Each c In .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
            cnt = 0
            ' Try and find the c value
            Set fnd = listrng.Find(what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, after:=listrng.Cells(listrng.Cells.Count))
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                ' Store the address of the first find so we can stop when we find it again!
                addr = fnd.Address
                ' Loop over all other matches in the range. By using a "Do ... Loop While"
                ' style loop, we ensure that the loop is run at least once!
                Do
                    ' Increase count and assign value to next column
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value = cnt
                    ' Find next match after current
                    Set fnd = listrng.Find(what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, after:=fnd)
                Loop While fnd.Address <> addr
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in making the declarations transparent. After that the programming is very easy.

```
Sub CountMatches()

    Dim Rng As Range                    ' "count" range (= column "B")
    Dim Itm As String                   ' item from the "items' column (= "A")
    Dim Rla As Long, Rlb As Long        ' last row in columns A and B
    Dim Ra As Long, Rb As Long          ' row counters
    Dim Counter As Long                 ' count matches

    With ActiveSheet
        ' look for the last used rows
        Rla = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Rlb = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        ' start looking for matches from row 2
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(Rlb, "B"))

        ' start looping in row 2
        For Ra = 2 To Rla
            Itm = .Cells(Ra, "A").Value
            If Len(Trim(Itm)) Then      ' skip if blank
                ' start comparing from row 2
                For Rb = 2 To Rlb
                    ' compare not case sensitive
                    If StrComp(.Cells(Rb, "B").Value, Itm, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        Counter = Counter + 1
                    End If
                Next Rb
                .Cells(Ra, "C").Value = Counter
                Counter = 0
            End If
        Next Ra
    End With
End Sub
```

Now the question is whether the transparency that workred for me appears transparent to you. I hope it does. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should be significantly faster.

```
Sub CountMatches_2()

    Dim Rng As Range                    ' "count" range (= column "B")
    Dim Itm As String                   ' item from the "items' column (= "A")
    Dim Rla As Long, Rlb As Long        ' last row in columns A and B
    Dim Ra As Long, Rb As Long          ' row counters

    With ActiveSheet
        ' look for the last used rows
        Rla = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Rlb = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        ' start looking for matches from row 2
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(Rlb, "B"))

        ' start looping in row 2
        For Ra = 2 To Rla
            Itm = .Cells(Ra, "A").Value
            If Len(Trim(Itm)) Then      ' skip if blank
                .Cells(Ra, "C").Value = Application.CountIf(Rng, Itm)
            End If
        Next Ra
    End With
End Sub
```

This code presumes that each item in column A is unique. If it is not duplicates will be created which, however, it would be easy to eliminate either before or after they are created.